# Dynamic javascript file with ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Before Core, we could simply do:

```
public JavascriptResult Global() {
    return Javascript("File");
}
```

and in that `File` we could easily place all our global variables in javascript instead place them in the page directly... a nice

```
<script src="/Scripts/Global" ></script>
```

would make a huge difference in code presentation ...

nowdays, using Core, we no longer have this available. I do understand why and I agree with most cases, but having all global variables (that are gather at runtime) is a must, and place them in a `script` tag is so much nicer than having all of them in the page directly.

**How are you** guys doing this now?

How can I easily put

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...

  @await Component.InvokeAsync("ShopLanguageKeys")
  @await Component.InvokeAsync("ShopMetaData")

  ...
```

as an external file instead of inline with the Layout page (as it's a huge block of javascript code)

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...

  <script src="/Scripts/Global"></script>

  ...
```

Can't find any good documentation on how to start with this...

Comment: Nothing prevents you from still having a route that returns JavaScript code instead of HTML. That still works in ASP.NET Core. I’m not sure what the `JavascriptResult` and that `Javascript` method is supposed to do in that case, but you can totally return `Content("window.foo = 'bar';", "text/javascript")` from a controller route. That being said, code that is gathered at runtime (and probably changes on every page?) is better placed inside the HTML so it’s not cached.

Comment: Why not to add these global variables in a JavaScript file directly and reference it in your HTML Layout? or you are generating this global variable thing dynamically ?

Comment: @HaithamShaddad all dynamic, as we can easily change/add/remove language-keys... @poke `JavascriptResult` returned a formatted javascript file, but I will give it a  try with the old `Content()`